# authorized code 401 using spring boot to create a bot

Tags: java, botframework

I use spring boot and botbuilder-java library to create a bot on microsoft teams. I registre my bot on bot framework. I use ngrok to make a proxy so that the bot frame can access to my local port. Then when i send a request and then response. I got com.microsoft.bot.connector.models.ErrorResponseException: Status code 401,

this is link which i follow to do.
https://medium.com/@oleksiydzhus/how-to-build-a-bot-with-microsoft-bot-framework-and-spring-boot-558fb32b7d3c

i already have the appId and appPassword, but when i send the response, the currentToken is null. I guess maybe this is the problem. but i don't know how to config it out.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class BotConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name = "credentials")
    public MicrosoftAppCredentials getCredentials() {
        return new MicrosoftAppCredentials("6b157339-e091-4c33-b9e3-7e7e035d006e", "<password>");
    }

    @Bean
    public List<ResourceResponse> getResponses(){
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

this is my handler

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/messages")
public class BotMessagesHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MicrosoftAppCredentials credentials;

    @Autowired
    private List<ResourceResponse> responses;

    @PostMapping(path = "")
    public List<ResourceResponse> create(@RequestBody @Valid
                                         @JsonDeserialize(using = DateTimeDeserializer.class) Activity activity) {

        ConnectorClient connector =
                new ConnectorClientImpl(activity.serviceUrl(), credentials);


        Activity echoActivity = ActivityCreator.createEchoActivity(activity);
        Activity checkedActivity = ActivityCreator.createSpellCheckedActivity(activity);
        Conversations conversation = ConversationCreator.createResponseConversation(connector);

        ResourceResponse echoResponse =
                ResourceResponseSender.send(conversation, activity, echoActivity);
        responses.add(echoResponse);

        ResourceResponse spellCheckedResponse =
                ResourceResponseSender.send(conversation, activity, checkedActivity);
        responses.add(spellCheckedResponse);

        return responses;
    }
}
```

```
com.microsoft.bot.connector.models.ErrorResponseException: Status code 401, 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at com.microsoft.rest.ServiceResponseBuilder.build(ServiceResponseBuilder.java:122) ~[client-runtime-1.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.AzureResponseBuilder.build(AzureResponseBuilder.java:56) ~[azure-client-runtime-1.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.bot.connector.implementation.ConversationsImpl.sendToConversationDelegate(ConversationsImpl.java:510) ~[bot-connector-4.0.0-a1.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.bot.connector.implementation.ConversationsImpl.access$200(ConversationsImpl.java:48) ~[bot-connector-4.0.0-a1.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.bot.connector.implementation.ConversationsImpl$12.call(ConversationsImpl.java:495) ~[bot-connector-4.0.0-a1.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.bot.connector.implementation.ConversationsImpl$12.call(ConversationsImpl.java:491) ~[bot-connector-4.0.0-a1.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error by following the instructions in the tutorial you linked. I noticed it's nearly a year old. You can find more recent builds of Bot Builder Java on MyGet: https://botbuilder.myget.org/gallery/botbuilder-v4-java-daily

When I tried running the sample from the Bot Builder Java GitHub repo I was able to talk to it in Teams without issue. Why not give that a try? https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java/tree/master/samples/bot-connector-sample

Comment: Thanks, I follow the Bot Builder Java GitHub repo same, it's work.